# GetX Translate long Map

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-getx

I use getx translate like the example:

```
return GetMaterialApp(
 translations: Messages(),
 locale: Get.deviceLocale,
 fallbackLocale: const Locale('pt','BR'), 
   (...)


class Messages extends Translations {   @override   Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
            "pt": {
              "titulo": "Ernesto Berg", 
              "subtitulo":"Habilidades Profissonais",
                   (...)
```

The problem is that my Messages class has a lot of information, and on some devices, when opening, the Messages is not read in time and text is not shown. Example printscreen below.

[All Read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOfoh.png)

[Not Read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNlXf.png)

Any suggestion to do this work? I think in doing a `wait` or using `compute()`
but I was not successful!

I will appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

first make a class of locales like this

```
`import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LocalStrings extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'Send': 'Send',
          'Choose your language': 'Choose your language',
        },
        'ar_001': {
    'Send': 'ارسال',
          'Choose your language': 'اختر لغتك',
        },
      };
}`
```

After this you have to set your locale in main.dart under GetMaterialApp. Make sure you are using GetX for that. `locale: Locale('ar_001'),`After this just write the same text you wrote in locale file and add tr after that `"Welcome Back To".tr,`   This will set your language based on your locale in main.dart file
If you want to change language just do `var locale = Locale('ar_001'); Get.updateLocale(locale);`this. This will update language
everywhere

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's not the point!. I know how to do all that. The problem is, I have lots of keys,  and some devices do not load all the content in start, and the information fails! (see the images I attached) I need to make the app force reading all keys before build layout!

Comment: I didn't encounter anything like this when I'm building my app. Other thing you can do is just show loading while the content is loading. After all the content is loaded show it on screen. You can use `Cupertino Activity Indicator` for that. I hope this will work.